# Running EventMachine in new Thread after Rails is loaded using Thin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eventmachine, thin

I have a Rails 3.2 app running on a Thin server and in application.rb I want to start EventMachine:

```
# application.rb

config.after_initialize do
  if ENV['EM']
    EM.run do
      host = '0.0.0.0'
      port = 3001

      # hit Ctrl + C to stop
      Signal.trap("INT")  { EventMachine.stop }
      Signal.trap("TERM") { EventMachine.stop }

      EventMachine::start_server host, port, SomeModule

      puts "EventMachine running on #{host}:#{port}. Ctrl + C to stop."
    end
  end
end
```

SomeModule has code that depends on Rails being loaded. That's why I put this in the after_initialize block instead of in an initializer.

Now when I start my server (with `rails s`) my output looks fine:

```
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 3.2.13 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
EventMachine running on 0.0.0.0:3001. Ctrl + C to stop.
```

But when I go to localhost in my browser I get a `204 No Content` response.

I can think of several things that causes this, but not a solution :)

- Maybe I'm starting the EventMachine on the same thread blocking the Rails app. But Thin should handle this right?
- Maybe I should start my server differently, but how then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some more Googling I found that since I'm using Thin I don't need to run another EventMachine.

My after_initialize block now looks like this:

```
config.after_initialize do
  include SomeModule
end
```

And in SomeModule I wrapped my code in an `EM.next_tick` block or I'd get a "eventmachine not initialized: evma_connect_to_server (RuntimeError)" error.

Using EventMachine in a Rails app with Thin was way easier than I thought :)

Comment: more info on the [EventMachine github wiki](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/wiki/FAQ#does-em-work-with-other-ruby-threads-running)

Answer (score 0):

You should prevent autoloading your ruby code that invokes EventMachine, otherwise it will block your main thread. Put your script to lib/daemons, then create a startup script for your EventMachine and use it as a daemon. I.e.:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# this is: ./scripts/my_daemon

require 'daemons'

options = {
  multiple: false,
  backtrace: true,
  app_name: 'my_daemon',
  dir_mode: :normal,
  dir: '/tmp/my_daemon',
  log_dir: '/tmp/my_daemon',
  log_output: true,
  ARGV: ARGV,
}

system "mkdir -p /tmp/my_daemons"
Daemons.run(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '../lib/daemons/my_daemon.rb'), options)
```

You'll need to add 'daemons' gem to your Gemfile.

Then just run `script/my_daemon start` from rails root. There are more commands:

- script/my_daemon stop   # stops the daemon
- script/my_daemon run    # runs in foreground, so you can see the output and debug it
- script/my_daemon status # shows if anything is running

You'll find logs in `/tmp/my_daemons/my_daemon.output`

Find more about daemons here: http://daemons.rubyforge.org/Daemons.html

Comment: In the meantime I found a solution. Do I need a daemon if I use Thin?

Comment: That depends on what problem you're solving. Daemons gem gives you more control over your background processes, it would decouple EventMachine from your main app, you would be able to start/stop it independently. And you can include config/environment.rb to get full env of your Rails app in your daemon. But since you found a simpler solution, it may work for you. :)

Comment: That sounds as something I might need in the future and I'll surely look into it. Thanks!